# Is assigning multiple variables to one string safe?

Tags: python

`None` is a singleton, so the following is safe:

```
a = b = None
```

Since strings and ints are immutable - and can only be changed via reassignment - is it safe for them too?

```
a  = b = 'test' # I cannot think of a case when this could cause problems
```

Comment: Yes, there's no way modifications to the string stored in `a` could propagate to `b`.

Comment: what do you mean by safe?

Comment: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-multi-variables-values/

Comment: "and can only be changed via reassignment " **strings and ints can't be changed at all**. That is what "immutable" means.

Comment: What kind of problem do you expect? a=b=stuff is the same as ```b=stuff ; a=b```. This is safe. Of course, if ```stuff``` is a structure that points to some data, then modifying b content's would modify a content. ```a=b=[12] ; a[0]=13``` makes ```b[0]``` 13. But that is the expected behavior. And it has nothing to do with the choice of writing ```a=b=[12]``` rather than ```b=[12] ; a=b```

Comment: You cannot assign anything to a string, I assume you mean "assign one strng to multiple variables".  Yes, it is safe.

Comment: Note even in that ```a=b=[12]``` example, modifying b does not change a. a and b are two different variables. Whose values happen to be the same. And here, the value is an array. So, sure, if you change array contents, as long as a and b are the same array, it change a and b contents, which is the same. But writing ```b=[15]``` for example would let a intact and still equal to ```[12]```

Comment: @chrslg Thanks, but please not that my quesion is about immutable types, not lists.

Comment: @barciewicz, yes, but lists are the canonical example for mutable types to use for contrast. Nobody here thinks your question is _about_ lists, but it's helpful to compare to demonstrate differences.

Comment: Yes I noted that. And the reason why is confusing to me. Why do you think there is something different, less safe, about mutable types. This is why I've used list as example to ask you whether it was because for list when we change content of a (not value of a, but content of list in a) it also change content of b?

Comment: ...in particular, demonstrating with lists lets folks demonstrate what kind of behavior we need to assume you're contrasting against when you call something "safe" -- because even though `a = b = []` can result in _unintuitive_ behavior, calling it _unsafe_ is... questionable.

Comment: The points about immutable types hold true too.  a = b = [1]; a is b -> true

Comment: I agree with Charles. What is the meaning of "safe" and "unsafe"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, I see your point. To demonstrate what I mean by **unsafe**: imagine API response like that `{data': data, 'errors': errors}`. Now if data in the response is manipulated by some post-request middleware, and assignment like  `data = errors = ['something']` was done before, `errors` would be changed as well.

Comment: Ok, so that was what I was talking about (list or dict have the same behavior you fear). But that has nothing to do with single-line assignment. You would have the same "problem" (I would argue that it is not a problem. It is the expected behavior. If you need a copy of the content, you have to copy it) if you were writing ```errors=['something']``` and then ```data=errors```

Comment: Note that "unsafe" is not the good wording here. Firstly, if you assume that someone has the ability to manipulate memory content of errors, then you must assume that they has the ability to manipulate memory content of data as well. Secondly, safety is relative to the application. It may be a far more serious problem for your application that data and errors have now different values when you expected them to be equal.

Comment: And thirdly, a post-request middleware, whatever it is, seems to me to be an external process, that could affect value in a network dataflow or something. Not really alter value of a variable

Comment: @chrslg: In Flask, there is `after_request` decorator that takes Response object as argument. So it has access to `data` and `errors` from my example and could in theory change either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement like `expr1 = expr2 = expr3` in Python is equivalent to the following

```py
tmp = expr3 # evaluate RHS

# left to right assignment to the temporary
expr1 = tmp
expr2 = tmp
```

If `expr1` and `expr2` are just variable names like `a` and `b`, then this means that `a` and `b` end up pointing to the same object.

```py
tmp = "test"
a = tmp
b = tmp
```

So if by "safe" you are worried about modifications to one affecting the other, then this would by default be unsafe, like if the RHS was a list, but for immutable objects like strings it would be safe since no modifications are possible.

Also note that reassigning a name in Python will never affect another name, even in the case of mutable objects.

```py
a = b = []

a[something] = something # can affect b
a.something = something # can affect b

a = something # cannot affect b
```

Background note: it is possible for `expr1` and `expr2` to be other things than just simple names, e.g. `a, b = a[:] = [[]], []`, but that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it like this?

```py
>>> a = b = None
>>> a = False
>>> print(b)
'False'
```

If so, you have nothing to worry about.

Otherwise, you need to explain more.

Comment: Thanks, but a, b = None causes a TypeError. Also, the question is not about None.

Comment: Technically, yes, you're right. It's only truthy when calling functions on the variables. I guess I was unclear. But on the other hand, ```None``` is just an example.

Comment: @barciewicz Well, then what the question is about? I have the feeling that you think we are all using bad faith to misunderstand your question. We are not.

Comment: I am new here, but I already know that when @CharlesDuffy doesn't understand the question, it means that it is not very understandable. I mean, when everybody is driving against the traffic, it is about time to wonder whether you are not the one driving against the traffic. When everybody's answer is not about the right question, it is about time to wonder whether the question is well worded.

Comment: @chrslg I appreciate all the efforts. But, to be fair, the question is clearly asking about immutable types, not None or mutable types.

Comment: No, you think it does because there are obviously some heavy misconception of what immutable types and variable affectations are. We are just trying to help you clarify those misconception. Because as is, your question makes no sense. No offense intended. That being said, you obviously don't want us to tell you that you don't understand thing. I wouldn't impose myself. So, I really hope someone will provide you the answer you want.